# Comparing date with NOW() in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a `column(expire_date(varchar))` with value stored like 2016-05-11 13:19:32. I want to compare this value with NOW(). I want to select the rows with the expiry_date greater than present time

My code:

```
select * from tbl_table where expiry_date > NOW()
```

But I don't know whether this is correct or not.

Comment: Try this query on mysql and you can see the returned data and then compare if its correct or not.

Comment: Do not store Dates as varchar. Store it as a date

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from tbl_table where CAST(expiry_date AS DATETIME) > NOW()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare DATETIME:

```
select * from tbl_table where str_to_date(expiry_date,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s") > NOW();
```

If you want to compare ONLY DATE:

```
select * from tbl_table where date(str_to_date(expiry_date,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s")) > curdate();
```

**Note:** Date should be stored as date or timestamp in database, instead of varchar [DATE in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of now() use current date() like:

```
select * from tbl_table where expiry_date > current_date();
```